# Express.js - Cookies Not Being Sent After 3 Hours of Running the Server

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, cookies, ubuntu-16.04

I have encountered an interesting issue that I don't know how to solve.

I built a simple website with a basic authentication back-end and everything works fine when I deploy it.

The database is working perfectly, the authentication middleware works exactly how it should, but suddenly when visiting the website and I try to log in a few hours later, I just get redirected with no cookies what so ever. (I tried it on multiple devices) 
The only thing that works is restarting the server process.

Technologies used:

- Server OS: Ubuntu 16.04.
- HTTP Server: Nginx(used as a reverse-proxy for the Node.js app)
- Process manager: pm2
- Database: MongoDB
- Express version: 4.16.3.

My login page code:

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
if (req.body.email && req.body.password){

  var email     = req.body.email;
  var password  = req.body.password;

  User.findOne({email})
  .then(user =>{
    if (!user) throw new Error("No user found.");
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    .then(correctPwd =>{
      if (!correctPwd) throw new Error("Wrong password.");
      return user.generateAuthToken();
    })
    .then(token => {


      // The problematic part

      res.cookie("auth", token, authCookie)
      .redirect(redirect); // redirect is a variable passed by a function


    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      res.status(400).redirect(redirect);
    })
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    res.clearCookie("auth").status(400).redirect(redirect);
  });
} else res.clearCookie("auth").status(400).redirect(redirect);
});
```

My Nginx config:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header P3P;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Comment: `console.log(err)` everywhere and see if you get an error after sometime?

Comment: Yeah I tried it in all the parts related to authentication. Pretty much with no results.

Comment: I have been thinking about trying to downgrade Express. Maybe there is some sort of a bug that causes the problems with cookies idk...

Comment: I edited it so it sends me a response with a "Logged in" message with the generated token but still doesn't pass any cookies. And again - it still works only for couple hours. Then it stops working again...

Comment: Interesting thing is that when I send the request using Postman, It receives the cookie back. But not when using a browser. (Tried Chrome and Firefox + couple mobile browsers)

Comment: Do you have a maxAge or expiry set on your cookies in the express config?

Comment: Are you using `socket.io` in your code?

Comment: @TarunLalwani No, I am not. @RedJandal Yes, I do. This is the cookie `var authCookie = {
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7200000), // 2h in miliseconds
  httpOnly: true,
  signed: true,
  secure: true // I am using HTTPS
}`

Comment: Please remove `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;`, all 3 they are needed for `socket.io` only

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thank you for noting this. I don't think it will solve the problem, but I just learned something new.

Comment: So the cookie expires after 2 hours which means the user has to be authenticated again. This is standard functionality am I missing something here?

Comment: @RedJandal Yes. I have also set the expiry on the jwt that is getting passed, so it has double protection. When the user is still on the site and the token & cookie are close to expiring, they get refreshed, so it just doesn't log them off while they are still using the site.

Comment: So I bypassed this problem by removing the cookie expiration and leaving it just on the token. But it still doesn't explain why the cookies don't get sent when they should... Thank you for your willingness to help guys! I will leave this thread open so if someone finds an explanation, he'll be able to let us know.